# I am trying to update data in database using get() method, but get() doesn't update in django

Tags: django, database

am trying to update using get() in django but not updated in databse while it gives message as it updated well

am trying to update using get() in django but not updated in databse while it gives message as it updated well, I tried to use filter() and it working well, but the problem is filter does not work professional in updating data, check my code below. please I want to use get() to make sure my things is updated well thank you.

```
@require_http_methods(["PATCH", "PUT"])

def update_product(request, id=None):

    items_from_user = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf8'))
    try:
        Product.objects.values().get(id=id).update(**items_from_user)

        return JsonResponse({ 'message': 'Product {} updated'.format(id) })

    except Product.DoesNotExist as error:

        return JsonResponse({ 'message': str(error) }, status=404)

    except Exception as error:

        return JsonResponse({ 'message': str(error) }, status=422)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
obj = Product.objects.get(id=id)
obj.__dict__.update(**items_from_user)
obj.save()
```

Your attempt would surely work like this:

```
Product.objects.values().get(id=id).update(field = 'value')
```

but not sure if it's ok with a dict as parameter.

Comment: have you ever tried with list, so I can convert dict into a list

Answer (score 0):

You can try filter. `Products.objects.filter(id=id).update(**items_from_user)`

Comment: the problem of is that, if I send id which is not in the database it show me as updated instead of providing error

Comment: You can do something like this to check if an object exists. if Products.objects.filter(id=id).exists():